# How can I compare similarities from a column of one Database table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Would anyone know the best way to compare a column of one database table to the column of another which are both on the same server. Im trying to find similarities between two unequal length columns.

Comment: Different databases on the same server or different servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your databases are on the same instance of SQL server you can easily access both tables like this and compare the columns

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test1.dbo.Table1 T1
JOIN Test2.dbo.Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

but when you want to use databases that are not on the same instance its is better to use tool like SSIS to birng data from two different data sources and do the com